# Increase the default docker storage driver (windowsfilter) in Windows Server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

The docker harddisk is getting 100% occupied for my running containers, in Windows Server 2019.

I'm guessing this is related to the docker storage driver getting occupied.

Ran "docker info" and got this:
Storage Driver: windowsfilter

[image: docker info command result]

Can you help me with:

1. Checking the current allotted size of the windowsfilter storage driver?
2. How to increase the size? (I got a couple of solutions like: docker run --storage-opt "size=50GB") but before that I need to know the current size of my storage driver.
3. Do I have to do this for separate containers or just once for all?

Appreciate your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#windowsfilter-options), the default is 20G.

Your solution of `docker run --storage-opt size=50G` will work for a **single** run of a container, yes.

If you want to adjust the default in Windows, edit the daemon.json file. It is located at `C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json` as documented on the [Docker daemon docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/). You may need to create it, if it does not exist. Note, you will likely need to recreate any containers after modifying that setting and restarting the docker service, in order for that to take affect.

Here is an example of setting the default size to 32GB in the daemon.json:

```
{
  "storage-opts": ["size=32GB"]
}
```

I was unable to determine a way to see the current size configuration from the docker command line though. Only the docker docs give any info on the default.